# IntelliJ IDEA - Run/debug doesn't copy resources

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, jboss

I have a maven project which is packaged as WAR. The POM looks something like the following:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <artifactId>my_app</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
           <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
              ...
            </plugin>
            ...
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

When I manually run the command `mvn package`, a WAR is generated with directory `target/my_app` where my web resources (JSP, CSS, JS, images, etc.) are copied to. The generated WAR, if uploaded to an Application Server, works fine.

However, if I use IntelliJ IDEA's Run/Debug configuration (which is configured to deploy the WAR to an Application Server (JBoss if that matters)) to do the same, I don't see the web resources. Only configuration XMLs and compiled classes is present in the `target/my_app` directory. The applicaiton server starts up all fine without any errors and  WAR is deployed successfully, however I can't accesss it as it returns 404.

How can I acheive what I get when building and manually uploading the WAR using *Run/Debug* of IntelliJ IDEA?

**UPDATE:**

Before launch tasks are:

- Build
- Build 'my_app:war exploded' artifact

Comment: What are the pre-launch tasks of your run/debug config? You can change the default "build" task to a maven run config for example.

Comment: @PimHazebroek Pre-launch tasks are:
- Build
- Build 'my_app:war exploded' artifact

Comment: I suggest to replace the prelaunch tasks with a maven run config to achieve the same result as you do when running the maven command manually. Alternatively you can also try the jboss application server integration to run / deploy to jboss immediately. (requires ultimate edition I guss)

Comment: @PimHazebroek I do have the Ultimate Edition and I do have setup Jboss Application server. Run/Debug configuration that I'm talking about is Run/Debug configuration of Jboss AS only.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue after installing 2018.1 IntelliJ IDEA. Reverting back to version 2017.3 solved the problem. It looks this is a bug with the new version since I had the same settings for both. Hope this helped.

Comment: Did you have the same setup? Maven project and Jboss as an Application Server?

Comment: @DilipRajBaral I was using Tomcat, but is InteliJ witch is supposed to make the build and copy/update the files. I have installed both versions with the same setup and on 2017 version all runs smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue in which when I was running from the command line then it was copying all the resources (example JSP etc.) but Intellij was not copying it.

As part of workaround I added the goal of 'war:exploded' along with 'compile' then it resolved my issue.

So in Maven config command line parameters will be (may differ for you):
clean compile war:exploded

Screenshot for reference.
[image]